# I am using GetDiskFreeSpaceExW

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, diskspace

I am using

```
 if( !GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(
        lpDirectoryName,                  // directory name
        &m_uliFreeBytesAvailable,         // bytes available to caller
        &m_uliTotalNumberOfBytes,         // bytes on disk
        &m_uliTotalNumberOfFreeBytes) )   // free bytes on disk
        return false;
else
        diskFreeSpaceInKB = static_cast<long int>(m_uliTotalNumberOfFreeBytes.QuadPart/ONE_KB_IN_BYTES)  ;
```

That returns negative value for disk that have a capacity greater than 1TB.
I need the accurate value representing the available disk space so that the user can record a movie if there is enough space on that disk.

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: What _exact_ values does the function return? Please show the values in hexadecimal.

Comment: UGS::System::SYSS_GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(
            GetLocation().c_str(),                     // directory name
            &iFreeBytesAvailable,        
            &iTotalNumberOfBytes,         
            &iTotalNumberOfFreeBytes      
            )    ;

        diskFreeSpaceInKB = static_cast<long int>(iTotalNumberOfFreeBytes.QuadPart/ONE_KB_IN_BYTES)  ;

Comment: @Divya please don't post code in a comment, instead edit your question and put your code _there_. And while you're at it do what I asked in my previous comment.

Comment: @Divya What is the type of `diskFreeSpaceInKB`? What __exact__ values does `getDiskFreeSPaceExW` return?

Comment: sizeof(long int) should be 4 by some compiler. ex: mingw64.

Comment: diskFreeSpaceInKB = static_cast<long long int>(m_uliTotalNumberOfFreeBytes.QuadPart/ONE_KB_IN_BYTES) ; try to use long long int

Comment: Voting to reopen, now that the question contains code showing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you typed `diskFreeSpaceInKB = static_cast<long int>...`, so I assume that `diskFreeSpaceInKB` is a `long int` variable.

First, let's have a look on the `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` prototype.

```
BOOL WINAPI GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR         lpDirectoryName,
  _Out_opt_ PULARGE_INTEGER lpFreeBytesAvailable,
  _Out_opt_ PULARGE_INTEGER lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
  _Out_opt_ PULARGE_INTEGER lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes
);
```

`PULARGE_INTEGER` = Pointer to `ULARGE_INTEGER`

ULARGE_INTERGER = [An union that stores a 64-bit unsigned integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383742(v=vs.85).aspx)

Now let's see what you did.

```
diskFreeSpaceInKB = static_cast<long int>(m_uliTotalNumberOfFreeBytes.QuadPart/ONE_KB_IN_BYTES)
```

In Windows, `int`/`long`/`long int` are always `signed 32-bit` regardless you're compiling 32-bit or 64-bit build because Windows uses [LLP64 model](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050131-00/?p=36563). So basically you're casting a `unsigned 64-bit integer` divided by `ONE_KB_IN_BYTES` to a `signed 32-bit integer`.

**So why I get negative number?**

Because the value exceeds the maximum positive value of the signed data type.

**How to fix it?**

Declare `diskFreeSpaceInKB` as `UINT64`, and `static_cast<UINT64>`.

Comment: Once you've fixed the declaration, I don't think you need the cast.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `__int64` instant of `long int`.
If is with large numbers like 1TB, that can be the problem and negative values is a classic signal of that.

1TB = 1.099.511.627.776 bytes

LONG_MAX = 2.147.483.647 bytes

[See this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx)